# How to plot zeros of a function as a thin stripe?

Tags: plotting, conditional

I have this function for $0<x<20$

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x];
```

and I want to graphically represent the points where this function is zero, as **a thin line stripe (not circles)** at $y=4$ with the following `PlotStyle` (something like the attached picture. There I have added those black lines manually, so they may not be in the correct position)

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.001]]
```

I wonder if someone could please show code to do that.

[image: plot with manually added root indicators]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function that draws short lines at the given positions `p`.

```
marker[p_] := Line[{p - {0, .1}, p + {0, .1}}]; 

f[x_] := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x];
points = {#[[1, 2]], 4} & /@ NSolve[f[x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.001]], 
 Prolog -> marker /@ points, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2.5, 4.5}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSolve` to calculate `f=0` points

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x];

points = {#[[1, 2]], 4} & /@ NSolve[f[x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x];
(*Out: {{0.935929, 4}, {2.57376, 4}, ...} *)
```

Use `Prolog` to draw points on plot + increase the `PlotRange` to make sure you can see the points:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.001]],

 Prolog -> Point[points],
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2.5, 4.5}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned in the question, I need those points as thin lines, not circles.

Comment: @sara96 You can use any type of graphics you like in `Prolog`, they don’t have to be points. You could use `Line` or `Rectangle` to reproduce the shape you want.

Answer (score 2):

My own preference is to use the `MeshFunctions` option of `Plot[]` to get the positions of the stripes (which avoids a separate use of `Solve[]`/`NSolve[]`), and then post-process accordingly:

```
Show[Normal[Plot[Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 20}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
                 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
                 MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"],
                                        Opacity[1], Thickness[0.001]]]] /. 
     Point[{x_, y_}] :> Line[{Scaled[{0., -0.01}, {x, 4.}], Scaled[{0., 0.01}, {x, 4.}]}], 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: zero-dashed plot]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x]
```

Yet another purely graphical method to identity and mark the zeros (without the need to use `Solve/NSolve` or post-processing) is to use `ContourPlot`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}, 
 Epilog -> ContourPlot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 3.75, 4.25}, 
    ContourStyle -> Black][[1]], 
 PlotRange -> {-2.5, 4.5}]
```

[image]

We get the same picture using:

```
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}],
 ContourPlot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 3.75, 4.25}, ContourStyle -> Black], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + 2 Cos[2 x]
```

You can use `NumberLinePlot` to identify and mark the zeros:

```
nlp = NumberLinePlot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0, 20}, Spacings -> 4, ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.001]]] /. 
  Point[x_] :> Line[Offset[{0, #}, x] & /@ {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

You can use `nlp` with `Show`

```
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}], nlp, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

or use `nlp[[1]]` as `Epilog` or `Prolog` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}, Epilog -> nlp[[1]], PlotRange -> {-2.5, 4.5}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]